# CURL script errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, mongoose

I am trying to test the `create` method in my curl scripts but when I run the command in terminal I am getting the errors:

> "{"error":{"message":"Cannot convert undefined or null to
>   object","error":{}}}scripts/jobs/create.sh: line 15: --data: command
>   not found"

**Here is what is in my jobs schema:**

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const jobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})
const Job = mongoose.model('Job', jobSchema)

module.exports = Job
```

**My jobs controller:**

```
'use strict'

const controller = require('lib/wiring/controller')
const models = require('app/models')
const Job = models.jobs

const create = (req, res, next) => {
  const job = Object.assign(req.body.job, {})
  Job.create(job)
    .then(job =>
      res.status(201)
        .json({
          job: job.toJSON()
          // ({ virtuals: true, user: req.user })
        }))
    .catch(next)
}

module.exports = controller({
  create
})
```

My `create` CURL script:

```
API="http://localhost:4741"
URL_PATH="/jobs"

curl "${API}${URL_PATH}" \
  --include \
  --request POST \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  # --header "Authorization: Token token=${TOKEN}" \
   --data '{
    "job": {
      "url": "'"${URL}"'"
    }
  }'

echo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURL scripts do not allow comments between the multi-line flags.

Remove `# --header "Authorization: Token token=${TOKEN}" \`

Or uncomment it if you need it.